# Reporting Statistics and Charts from Firebase Database

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database

I am recording a heap of data from a game I developed.  The data is structured as follows:

```
{
  "games" : {
    "gamerhandle123" : {
    "170730060619719" : {
      "discardPlayer" : 3,
      "handle" : "gamerhandle123",
      "level" : 3,
      "roundNo" : 0,
      "winningAmount" : 192,
      "winningLevel" : 7,
      "winningPlayer" : 0,
      "winningTiles" : "C1C1C1C2C3C4C9C9C9C2C2C7C7C2"
    },...
```

A record is created at the end of each game.  I calculate a DateTimeMS to get a game id and structure each game within the gamer handle (Google Game Services ID).

This is all great, but now I want to be able to perform various statistical calculations, counts, measure and chart gamer performance over time.

My game has about 30k games per day, and what I would like to do is present data back to the players to show their performance over time, and how they compare to the best players.

I have a few questions:

1) How do I do a count of games in total and per player?

2) How do I group up this data (i.e. winningAmount) by player ?

3) What is the best charting library to use with Android?

Thanks in advance for any help or direction?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question because it might help someone else.

You can create backups from your firebase database to Google Cloud Services, and then import the backups into BigQuery for analysis.

You automate your backups using this documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/backups

Then you import your data using this process:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#loading_json_files